# Do I need separate Twitter apps for integration with iOS and Android apps + Web?

Tags: android, ios, twitter, sharing, web

I'm working on a project which has iOS and Android native apps, plus a Website; with all 3 channels featuring content sharing via Twitter. Sharing must of course be done by integrating a Twitter app with these channels.

Now, the norm used to be that we'd need separate apps for this purpose; most notably with changes to the App Type selection (Browser vs. Client) and the Callback URL.

Perhaps this is old news, but we noticed recently that Twitter apps Settings no longer have a Browser/Client setting and seems to suggest a universal approach for all channels. I've done some R&D, but was unable to get the same twitter app working with different channels.

Was wondering whether anyone out there has experience in such a scenario; i.e. utilizing a single Twitter app for multiple channels, and whether this is a possibility.

Thanks.

(P.S. > I did try this out on the Twitter forums, but no luck :( )

Comment: yeah, I think this is a borderline [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) question. Your asking about registering a new application with Twitter?

Comment: Hi Ilya, not quite, I'm taking about using the same Twitter application for content sharing across both native mobile apps and websites. (i.e integrating the same Twitter app with iOS, Android AND the web code to enable sharing over Twitter for users of all three channels) - Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure I completely understand the question then. Maybe somebody knows better. Whats the link to the question in the Twitter forums?

Comment: Here you go > https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1392. Thanks again for looking into this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some answers on the Twitter forums, plus some personal R&D work, I've concluded that this IS now possible. i.e. that the same same Twitter application can be used across different channels. The browser / client differentiation no longer applies in these apps, and its possible to work with a callback URL in different channels to work it out.

The only caveat is that for iOS applications, you will need to set up sending of the PIN authenticator which will will result in the Twitter app working well.

We've been using the following library for this purpose, and it'll work well with some tweaking >
https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth